# Trouble retrieving emoji messages in SQL query and ignored or treated as empty string

Tags: sql

I have the "" emoji stored as a message in my database. When I execute my store procedure to retrieve records where

```
select top 10 * 
from t_MemberApp_PushNotifications 
where contactID = 10930547 
  and pushMessage <> '' 
order by 1 desc
```

It doesn't display the data when only emoji is present. As you can see the attached images.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

I attempted to understand the issue by referring to the provided link, and you can utilize it to address my concern on a SQL Fiddle.
[Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/cvF0FP3k)

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed conflicting tags here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: I tried it but the query still ignoring emoji record. Is there any other way?

Comment: Note to mention: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use N for indicating UNICODE string

```
Select top 10 * from t_MemberApp_PushNotifications 
where contactID = 10930547 and pushMessage <> N'' order by 1 desc
```

You can use len()

```
Select top 10 * from t_MemberApp_PushNotifications 
where contactID = 10930547 and LEN(pushMessage) >0  order by 1 desc
```

Comment: The condition pushMessage <> N'' didn't work for me, but I found a solution by using `LEN()`. 

Comment: I mentioned that as well, I'm glad it helps